# How does this behaviour work with Ruby and HTTParty?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm learning Ruby.

I have some code that uses the HTTParty library to download some data. The remote server does not correctly define the content-type so the response is not parsed (as JSON) automatically.

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{"response":{ ............ }}
```

In the code is the following line:

```
if resp['response'] == 'response'
```

In the case that the response is automatically parsed this behaves as expected and `{ .......... }` from the original JSON would be returned. In the case that it is not parsed it returns the string `response` and I cannot figure out why it does that.

Which feature of the HTTParty library causes it to return the string `response`?
A different request that results in plain text data returns Nil when trying to access `['response']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I now understand it. The `resp['response']` tries to call the `[]` method on the resp object but since this is not defined the `method_missing` method is invoked

```
# the method_missing from HTTParty::Response
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if parsed_response.respond_to?(name)
    $stdout.puts parsed_response.class.inspect
    $stdout.puts parsed_response.inspect
    parsed_response.send(name, *args, &block)
  elsif response.respond_to?(name)
    response.send(name, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

In the case where the JSON is not parsed the `parsed_response` is actually a String. The String class in Ruby defines `[]` such that when given a string like `response` as the argument the same string is returned back but only in the case that it exists within the entire string.

Since the JSON string did contain `"response"` the `response` value was returned.